interact with etherscan.io
I want to interact with etherscan.io.
I work with windows powershell.
I created a npm init and install web3.js.
I created a neweb3 using const { Web3 } = require('web3');
answer : undefined
I created a connection with etherscan.io using const web3 = new Web3('https://etherscan.io/');
answer undefined
now when I created the following request web3.eth.getBalance('an ethereum adress');
The answer is  Uncaught:
[FetchError: invalid json response body at https://etherscan.io/ reason: Unexpected token '<', "
<!doctype "... is not valid JSON] {
Before all this I made all the request with ganache with no problem.Could you help me? Thank for all.

etherscan isn't an rpc provider, have a look on https://chainlist.org/ and get an rpc from there or sign up to somewhere like https://alchemy.com/, then connect to that. etherscan provide api, though doesn't sound like that is what you looking for.
